# Bind different values in multiple textbox with same ngModel property in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to create a time-picker. The picker will be opened when the user focuses on a text-box. Now, a single page may contain multiple text-boxes, for each of which the picker should be opened. The issue I am facing is, I get the values from time-picker for different text-boxes, but when binding to `ngModel`, any selected value gets bound to all the text-boxes.

Let me show you my approach:

**component.html**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="pickerData" (focus)="initPicker($event)" id="f-1" /> 
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="pickerData" (focus)="initPicker($event)" id="f-2" />
<div #timepicks></div> <!-- Here where the picker will be dynamically Injected -->
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener, ViewContainerRef, 
ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
import { TimepickComponent } from './timepick/timepick.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   pickerData: any;
   @ViewChild('timepicks', {read: ViewContainerRef, static: false}) timepicks: ViewContainerRef;

   constructor(
     private _componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
    ) {}

   ngOnInit() {

   }

   initPicker = (event) => {
     this.timepicks.clear();
     let pickerComponentFactory = 
     this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TimepickComponent);

     //Dynamically creating the ' TimepickComponent ' component
     let pickerComponentRef = this.timepicks.createComponent(pickerComponentFactory); 
     (<TimepickComponent>(pickerComponentRef.instance)).pickerId = event.target.id; // Passing id

     pickerComponentRef.instance.pickData.subscribe(res => {
      this.pickerData = res;
      pickerComponentRef.destroy();
    });
  }
}
```

**Timepickcomponent.ts**

```
  .....
  .....

  @Input() pickerId: any;
  @Output() pickData = new EventEmitter();

 .....
 .....

   setClose = () => {
     this.pickData.emit(this.valueHolder); // Emitting as output
   }
```

**Current Output**

Screenshot 1

[image]

screenshot 2

[image]

As it can be seen, screen1 is opening based on text-box id, but in screen2, when I select and set, it gets populated in another text-box. Ideally, the selected picker from a text-box should bind with that particular text-box.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a demo?

Comment: sure, can you help me on how to do that. I am new to SO and do not know how to create demo

Comment: Here is a stacklitz link- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9bpe1r add your component there

Comment: Added @PrashantPimpale

Comment: Can you share the live link?

Comment: Here is the link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tfr4qy

Comment: You have to use diff variables for two textboxex

Comment: @PrashantPimpale currently that is not possible. reason being, the html input fields will be rendered thru a loop dynamically based on a JSON, so the identifier will be based on id

Comment: Check the posted answer, if it work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use Document Service to access the element and set the value for clicked input control:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" (focus)="initPicker($event)" id="f-1" /> &nbsp;
<input type="text" (focus)="initPicker($event)" id="f-2" />
<div #timepicks></div>
```

- Removed Two way data binding

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { TimepickComponent } from './timepick/timepick.component';
// Added Document reference
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'timepicker';
  isVisible: boolean = false;
  pickerData: any;
  @ViewChild('timepicks', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: false }) timepicks: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: HTMLDocument,
    private _componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  initPicker = (event) => {
    this.timepicks.clear();
    let pickerComponentFactory = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TimepickComponent);
    let pickerComponentRef = this.timepicks.createComponent(pickerComponentFactory);
    (<TimepickComponent>(pickerComponentRef.instance)).pickerId = event.target.id;

    pickerComponentRef.instance.pickData.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(event.target.id);
      if (res) {
        (<HTMLInputElement>this.document.getElementById(event.target.id)).value = res;
      }
      pickerComponentRef.destroy();
    });
  }
}
```

- Import `Inject from @angular/core` and `DOCUMENT from @angular/common`
- Injected in constructor: `@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: HTMLDocument`
- Used `(<HTMLInputElement>this.document.getElementById(event.target.id)).value = res;` to set the value attribute of clicked input element

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yxlp1x)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you were binding both the input boxes with same variable **pickerData**. So, even if you change any one of them, the change will be reflected for both the values.
Since you have two textboxes you need two variables to store their values, like **pickerData1** and **pickerData2**.

While calling the **initPicker()** you need to pass one more parameter i,e in which textbox the datepicker is currently being opened and store the date in that respective variable.

Html code

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="pickerData1" (focus)="initPicker($event, 1)" id="f-1" /> 
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="pickerData2" (focus)="initPicker($event, 2)" id="f-2" />
```

TS code

```
initPicker = (event, index) => {
     this.timepicks.clear();
     let pickerComponentFactory = 
     this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TimepickComponent);

     //Dynamically creating the ' TimepickComponent ' component
     let pickerComponentRef = this.timepicks.createComponent(pickerComponentFactory); 
     (<TimepickComponent>(pickerComponentRef.instance)).pickerId = event.target.id; // Passing id

     pickerComponentRef.instance.pickData.subscribe(res => {
      if (index === 1)
          this.pickerData1 = res;
      elseif (index === 2)
          this.pickerData2 = res;
      pickerComponentRef.destroy();
    });
```

Comment: Imagine you have 30 pickers then you have to define 30 variables + passing hardcoded value like 1 and 2 will be more error prone and time consuming in terms of maintaince

Comment: Yeah, in such case we should store the values in an array.